# ListView item background color

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a ListView in which every second item should have a different color (for example: white -> gray -> white ->gray  etc.), it seems to work initially but as soon as I start scrolling, the rendering of the backgroundcolor seems to fail: the other color is set randomly to the items, also when I scroll up again this happens to the items where the color was correct at the beginning. Can someone hint me why this is happening?

I have tried this in the Adapter:

```
    if((position % 2) == 1) {
        layoutHolder.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green));
    }
```

and this in my ListFragment:

```
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> fillList = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        addListItems();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        for (int i = 1; i < getListView().getChildCount()-1; i = i+2) {
            LOGI(TAG, "for-loop " + String.valueOf(i));
            getListView().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getSherlockActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green));
        }
    }   
};
```

**UPDATE:**

I have done a bit of logging and found out that, if I am adding more elements than visible on the screen and check for the ListViews child count, the ListView only holds the children which are initially visible to the screen, the rest seems to be loaded/added when scrolling is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your adapter use this code.. its work.. u need to provide else condition.

```
if ( position % 2 == 0 ){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }else{
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
```

[image]

Comment: ... didn't worked, also I don't see why the else condition should be implied, default color is white, and if I'm just changing the odd (or even) positions, the other rows should'nt be affected at all

Comment: Sorry my fault, your solution is correct. I had created the inner layout programmatically outside if (convertView == null), now I have put it inside the if clause and just put the color changing outside and now it works... but I still don't get it way the system needs the else clause to render properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Adapter's getView()

```
if((position % 2) == 1) {
                  LayoutHolder.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}else{
            LayoutHolder.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.gray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in onPostExecute()

```
getListView().getChildAt(i).setCacheColorHint(getSherlockActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green));
```

Comment: Didn't work setCacheColorHint can only be applied on the Listview itself and not to the child element